# $ionicModal cannot access the controller

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ionic-framework

I'm following the [Ionic Books](http://ionicframework.com/docs/guide/building.html) to learn Ionic. And I'm trying to make an ionic modal. The modal shows as I expected. However, I found that my modal cannot be closed as I click the button with attribute `ng-click="closeCreateNewTaskModal()"` in the modal view. And it seems like I cannot access the variable member of `$scope`. So I guess the modal view cannot get to my controller. But I don't know why?

The body section of my HTML:

```
<body ng-app="starter" ng-controller="TodoCtrl">

<ion-side-menus>
  <ion-side-menu-content>
    <ion-header-bar class="bar-dark">
      <h1 class="title">Ionic Blank Starter</h1>
      <button class="button button-icon" ng-click="openCreateNewTaskModal()"><i class="icon ion-compose"></i></button>
    </ion-header-bar>
    <ion-content>
      <ion-list>
        <ion-item ng-repeat="task in s.currentProject.tasks">{{task.name}}</ion-item>
      </ion-list>
    </ion-content>
  </ion-side-menu-content>
  <ion-side-menu side="left">
    <ion-header-bar class="bar-dark">
      <h1 class="title">Projects</h1>
    </ion-header-bar>
    <ion-content>
      <ion-list>
        <ion-item ng-repeat="project in projectList" ng-click="s.currentProject = project">{{project.name}}</ion-item>
      </ion-list>
    </ion-content>
  </ion-side-menu>
</ion-side-menus>

<script id="new-task.html" type="text/ng-template">
  <ion-modal-view>
    <ion-header-bar class="bar-secondary">
      <h1 class="title">Add Task</h1>
      <button class="button button-clear button-positive" ng-click="closeCreateNewTaskModal(false)">Cancel</button>
    </ion-header-bar>
    <ion-content>
      <form ng-submit="closeCreateNewTaskModal(true)">
        <div class="list">
          <label class="item item-input">
            <input type="text" ng-model="newTask.name">
          </label>
        </div>
      </form>
      <div class="padding">
        <button type="submit" class="button button-block button-positive">Create</button>
      </div>
    </ion-content>
  </ion-modal-view>
</script>

</body>
```

And the controller in my `app.js`:

```
.controller('TodoCtrl', function ($scope, $ionicModal) {
  $scope.projectList = [
    {
      name: "Android",
      tasks: [
        { name: "Download Android Studio" },
        { name: "Download ADK" },
        { name: "Build Gradle" },
        { name: "Deploy the App" }
      ]
    },
    {
      name: "iOS",
      tasks: [
        { name: "Download XCode" },
        { name: "Start simulator" }
      ]
    }
  ];
  $scope.s = {};
  $scope.s.currentProject = $scope.projectList[0];

  $scope.modal = null;
  $ionicModal.fromTemplateUrl("new-task.html", {
    $scope: $scope,
    animation: "slide-in-up"
  }).then(function (modal) {
    $scope.modal = modal;
  });

  $scope.openCreateNewTaskModal = function () {
    console.log("openCreateNewTaskModal");
    $scope.newTask = {
      name: "Abc"
    };
    if ($scope.modal) $scope.modal.show();
  };
  $scope.closeCreateNewTaskModal = function () {
    console.log("closeCreateNewTaskModal");
    if (false) {
      $scope.s.currentProject.tasks.push(angular.extend({}, $scope.newTask));
    }
    if ($scope.modal) $scope.modal.hide();
  };
})
```

Answer (score 0):

I found the problem. It is because that I set the `$scope` option, however the option name should be `scope`

```
  $ionicModal.fromTemplateUrl("new-task.html", {
    $scope: $scope,  // this should be `scope`
    animation: "slide-in-up"
  }).then(function (modal) {
    $scope.modal = modal;
  });
```

Comment: Oh, you beat me to it. :) Good job!

Answer (score 0):

Two things I noticed:

1: The ionic modal service's 'fromTemplateUrl' function's second parameter takes an object. One of the properties of that object is 'scope' and expects a scope object, which you gave to it ($scope, in your case). But you also wrote '$scope' as the name of that property. Hence you are setting your controller's $scope object as the value of a property that is not picked up by the modal, while the 'scope' property remains undefined.

```
{ $scope: $scope }
```

should be

```
{ scope: $scope }
```

2: You're using a boolean inside your closeCreateNewTaskModal function, but you forgot to declare it as one of it's argument.

```
closeCreateNewTaskModal(hastask) { 
            if(!hasTask) { ... } ... }
```

Comment: Thx so much! The boolean argument was there before, but I removed it when debugging, forget it. :)